# Could someone explain this erlang function to round a number to a specific amount of decimal places?

Tags: recursion, erlang

```
round(Number, Precision) ->
    Power = math:pow(10, Precision),
    round(Pi * Power) / Power.
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how this function actually works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have a mistake in the function.  It should be:

```
round(Number, Precision) ->
    Power = math:pow(10, Precision),
    round(Number * Power) / Power.
```

With `Number = 10.23456` and `Precision = 2`, the line:

```
Power = math:pow(10, Precision)
```

results in:

```
Power = 10 * 10 = 100
```

And `Number * Power` is equal to:

```
 10.23456 * 100
```

which is:

```
 1023.456
```

Then, `round(1023.456)` is equal to:

```
1023
```

Dividing that number by Power, or 100, gives you:

```
10.23
```

The algorithm you are using works like this:

1. Move the number of decimal places you are interested in keeping to the left of the decimal point.  If you want to keep one decimal place, you multiply the number by 10 (=> 102.3456); if you want to keep two decimal places, you multiply the number by 100 (=> 1023.456); if you want to keep 3 decimal places, you multiply the number by 1000 (=> 10234.56); etc.
2. Get rid of everything to the right of the decimal point using round().
3. Move the number of decimal places you wanted to keep back to the right of the decimal point.

So, if you have the number 10.23456 and you want to keep 1 decimal place, if you follow the steps in the algorithm you get:

1. 102.3456
2. 102
3. 10.2

With the number 10.23456 and wanting to keep 2 decimal places, if you follow the steps in the algorithm you get:

1. 1023.456
2. 1023
3. 10.23

With the number 10.23456 and wanting to keep 3 decimal places, if you follow the steps in the algorithm you get:

1. 10234.56
2. 10234
3. 10.234